# Why won't cron run my sh script?

Tags: scripts, cron

Used gnome-schedule to create a script to set my headset as the fallback audio device because it keeps unsetting it when the headset gets disconnected or pc goes into sleep mode.

Anyway, crontab is this:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/dmitry/bin
* * * * * headsetfix
```

/home/dmitry/bin/headsetfix is

```
#!/bin/sh
pacmd set-default-sink alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Inc_Logitech_USB_Headset_H540_00000000-00-H540.analog-stereo
pacmd set-default-source alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Inc_Logitech_USB_Headset_H540_00000000-00-H540.analog-stereo
```

It runs fine from the terminal.
I've made sure it's chmodded to be executable, and "which headsetfix", run from cron, outputs "/home/dmitry/bin/headsetfix" so not sure what the problem is.

Comment: How you access the cron tab? `sudo cron -e`? or `cron -e`?

Comment: just "crontab -e"

Comment: Not pretty sure why this doesn't work, but can you try changing the last line of your crontab to `* * * * * sh headsetfix`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help.
Maybe the fact that it writes to stdout has to do with it?

`dmitry@dmibuntu:~$ sh /usr/local/bin/headsetfix
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> >>> Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> >>> dmitry@dmibuntu:~$ `

Comment: Screw it, it'll probably be easier to just have a separate script run headsetfix and then sleep for a bit, looping forever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot create a crontab job for my scrapy program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288111/cannot-create-a-crontab-job-for-my-scrapy-program)

Comment: Dunno man it's been over 7 years since I faced this problem. My current system doesn't even have cron so who knows.