# Cannot create a crontab job for my scrapy program

Tags: command-line, python, google-chrome, cron, selenium

I have written a small Python scraper (using Scrapy framework). The scraper requires a headless browse... I am using ChromeDriver.

As I am running this code on an Ubuntu server which does not have any GUI, I had to install Xvfb in order to run ChromeDriver on my Ubuntu server ([I followed this guide](https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-chromedriver-on-ubuntu/))

This is my code:

```py
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my_spider'

    def __init__(self):
        # self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I can run the above code from Ubuntu shell and it execute without any errors:

```
ubuntu@ip-1-2-3-4:~/scrapers/my_scraper$ scrapy crawl my_spider
```

Now I want to setup a cron job to run the above command everyday:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/
05 12 * * * cd /home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper && scrapy crawl my_spider >> /tmp/scraper.log 2>&1
```

but the crontab job gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 192, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 196, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 86, in crawl
    self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 98, in _create_spider
    return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 19, in from_crawler
    spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper/my_scraper/spiders/spider.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 5.4.0-1029-aws x86_64)
```

### Update

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117377/selenium-with-chromedriver-doesnt-start-via-cron) help me solve the issue (but I don't quite understand why)

I ran `echo $PATH` on my Ubuntu shell and copied the value into the crontab:

```
PATH=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
05 12 * * * cd /home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper && scrapy crawl my_spider >> /tmp/scraper.log 2>&1
```

---

*Note: As I have created a bounty for this question, I am happy to award it to any answer which explains why changing the PATH solved the issue.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the reason of almost all the cases where `cron` doesn't seems to run.

[Cron always runs with a mostly empty environment](https://serverfault.com/a/337921/407820). `HOME`, `LOGNAME`, and `SHELL` are set; and a very limited `PATH`. It is therefore advisable to use complete paths to executables, and export any variables you need in your script when using `cron`.

You can also:

- [Use the environment variables you use on your shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27291/209677)
- [Simulate it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2546509/4970442), by temporarily adding this to your crontab and wait a minute to save the cron environment to `~/cronenv` (then you can remove this):

  ```
  * * * * * env > ~/cronenv
  ```

  Then test running a shell (by default, `SHELL=/bin/sh`) with exactly that environment:

  ```
  env - $(cat ~/cronenv) /bin/sh
  ```
- [Force the crontab to run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42715/how-can-i-make-cron-run-a-job-right-now-for-testing-debugging-without-changing).

Also, you [**can't** use variable substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use?answertab=votes#comment25414017_10657111) as in shell, so a declaration like `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` is interpreted literally.

Comment: Thanks for this Pablo, just one question, when I set the PATH in a cronjob, is the PATH modified within the scope of that cronjob only, or does it change $PATH variable that is used everywhere else on Ubuntu?

Comment: Neither. If you set the variable at the beginning of the crontab will be there only for following cron lines. You can set a variable [only for a line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126942/209677), though. You might also find useful [to `export`](https://superuser.com/q/18988/500826), and setting `* * * * * /usr/bin/env > /tmp/env_on_crontab`.

Comment: Ah, thanks... I actually have 2 lines in my crontab... the job is executed twice a day, morning and evening... so do I need to set the path two times in the crontab? i.e. once before each line?

Comment: Only one is necessary. Also, you probably will need only one cron line. Check with [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/)

Answer (score 1):

The commands `readlink`, `dirname` and `cat` could not be located because `/bin` is not included in the `PATH` environment variable.

Explain

> unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
> The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.

Try to set `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/` and execute
`/usr/bin/google-chrome --no-sandbox --headless --disable-dev-shm-usage` you'll get

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 8: readlink: command not found
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 10: dirname: command not found
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 45: exec: cat: not found
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 46: exec: cat: not found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this one. Crontab opens a new shell for user ubuntu.

```
05 12 * * *   su - ubuntu -c 'cd /home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper && scrapy crawl my_spider >> /tmp/scraper.log 2>&1'
```