# My cron doesn't find a file

Tags: bash, scripts, python, cron, automation

I have written a Python script that I would like to run by crontab!
I have run the Python script individually and it works fine!
The problem is that when I run it by Crontab, I receive an error indicating that one of the Python files that it called does not exist.

The error in `/tmp/listener.log` is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/telegram/sendmsg.py", line 21, in <module> 
  file = open("List.csv") 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'List.csv'
```

Despite the fact that my file exists and it runs when I run my script without crontab!

I have my crontab set up like this:

```
30 14 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/tele/msg.py > /tmp/listener.log 2>&1
```

My Code:

```
import csv
from datetime import date
from timeIR import *
from persiantools.jdatetime import JalaliDate
from persiantools import characters, digits
import requests

def send_to_telegram(message):

    apiToken = '****'
    chatID = '***'
    apiURL = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{apiToken}/sendMessage'

    try:
        response = requests.post(apiURL, json={'chat_id': chatID, 'text': message })
        print(response.text)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

file = open("List.csv")
data = csv.reader(file)
data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")

whoisinshift = []
shiftname = []
phone = []

today=digits.fa_to_en(ShowDateDay())

for row in data:
    listdate = row[0]
    if listdate==today:
        mydate=digits.fa_to_en((ShowTodayFull()))
        whois=row[1]
        phonenumber=row[2]
file.close()

mymsg=u"\U0001F4C5"+"\t"+mydate+"\n"+u"\uE13B"+"\t"+whois+"\n"+u"\U0001F4F1"+"\t"+phonenumber
send_to_telegram(mymsg)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot create a crontab job for my scrapy program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288111/cannot-create-a-crontab-job-for-my-scrapy-program)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message clearly states, the problem is that the script can't find the file `List.csv` (when run with Cron), because you haven't stated the full path.

Edit line 21 in your script to:

```
file = open("/root/telegram/List.csv")
```

Then your script will work, even with Cron.